# R reprojecting map to lat/long

Tags: r, dictionary, map-projections

I used mapproj package to convert set of lat/long into map projection (in this example lagrange). Next I used it to define several other points on the space. I now want to convert those new points back into lat/long, but mapproj does not offer such function, nor did I found it elsewhere.

```
cord<-data.frame(x, y)

lagrange<-mapproject(cord$x, cord$y, projection="lagrange")
#Some  
#clustering
#here

#Here are cluster centers, but in the form of lagrange projection. I want a lat/long cord of them
cluster.centers
```

How to do it in R?

Comment: Check the `rgdal` package and the `project` function (in particular the `inv` argument).

Answer (score 2):

I read the package documentation and I don't believe that the author intended his set of projections to be used beyond plotting.

The 'standard' way to work with geospatial data in R is through the set of *sp* objects.  The way to transform sp objects is through *spTransform*.  Both the objects and methods can be found in the *sp* package.  There should be a number of tutorials available, admitedly this can be a steep learning curve if you are not familiar with GIS and R.

An example of converting 'long lat' data to other projections is detailed in this post:

[Error when re-projecting spatial points using spTransform in rgdal R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974785/error-when-re-projecting-spatial-points-using-sptransform-in-rgdal-r)